# How to Check logged in user for multiple Roles in Asp.Net membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, roles

I have programmatically bind repeater in my code behind file. I am also checking for roles in my page like below and according to that I am binding my repeater control like this;

```
if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    repeaterArticlesList.DataSource = ArticleAccess.GetArticlesWithNoPaginate();
    repeaterArticlesList.DataBind();
}
else if(Page.User.IsInRole("Editor"))
{
    repeaterArticlesList.DataSource = ArticleAccess.GetArticlesWithNoPaginate();
    repeaterArticlesList.DataBind();
}
else 
{
    string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    repeaterArticlesList.DataSource = ArticleAccess.GetArticlesWithNoPaginateWithUsername(userName);
    repeaterArticlesList.DataBind();
}
```

I have total 4 roles i-e **Admin, Author, Editor, User**. However, I have one user i-e **admin** which belongs to all of these roles. 
The problem with my logic is that when I logged in as an admin user (which belongs to all 4 roles), the first condition and the second condition both fails and the last one is executed.
So, **I want to execute my first condition for that user which must be in all of my roles 4 roles.**
Otherwise then I will check for individual roles.
Any help regard to this is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName);
var rolesNotAssigned = Roles.GetAllRoles().Except(userRoles);
if (rolesNotAssigned.Length == 0)
{
    // user is in all roles   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin") && Page.User.IsInRole("Editor") && Page.User.IsInRole("Author") && Page.User.IsInRole("User"))
{
  //
}
    //Only for users that are in all roles
    if (Roles.GetAllRoles().Length == Roles.GetRolesForUser().Length)
    {
    }
```

Comment: this is not a professional way and is not executing

Comment: Is new line of code executing?